# Not able to configure ssh key for git

Tags: github

I followed the steps provided in the github. but stil i'm not able to create ssh properly.
when i run ssh-add -l it shows the agent has no identities. But when i try to create new ssh key then it says id_rsa and id_rsa.pub are already exists.

But it is not identifying the existing ssh keys. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the key to ssh-agent:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```